# realm transaction in BroadcastReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, realm, android-broadcastreceiver

I show a notification with actions to the user, I handle these actions with a BroadcastReceiver, from there I update a realm database, but it doesn't get updated, even though I'm sure(through logs) the transaction gets executed.

NotificationBroadcastReceiver:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val notionId = intent.getStringExtra(NOTION_ID_EXTRA)
        val actionType = intent.getIntExtra(ACTION_TYPE, ACTION_TYPE_PUTBACK)

        when (actionType) {
            ACTION_TYPE_PUTBACK -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.notion_is_putback, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            ACTION_TYPE_ARCHIVE -> {
                NotionsRealm.changeIdleState(notionId, true)
            }
        }

        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancel(NotionsReminder.NOTION_NOTIFICATION_ID)

}
```

NotionsRealm:

```
fun changeIdleState(id: String, state: Boolean) {
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    realm.executeTransaction {
        val notion = it.where<Notion>().equalTo("id", id).findFirst()

        notion?.isArchived = state
        debug("${notion?.isArchived}") //prints true to the log, but the data doesn't change.
    }
    closeRealm(realm)
}

private fun closeRealm(realm: Realm) {
    try {
        realm.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        error(e)
    } finally {
        debug("realm closed")
    }
}
```

---

**edit**:
I just let the receiver start an empty activity(with no layout) to handle the database. the same thing happened. I think it's no longer a BroadcastReceiver issue. It's strange, other realm transactions run perfectly in other activities/fragments.

Comment: How do you verify that "Realm doesn't get updated"?

Comment: I have a fragment that shows this data, and whether it's been archived or not. Also, this notification sends the same "notion" every time to the receiver, instead of showing the next non-archived notion, even though it shouldn't, as this notion just got archived by the receiver. And this notification is only interested in non archived notions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not a problem with realm, it was How I fired the broadcast, I did it this way:

```
fun notificationAction(context: Context, id: String, actionType: Int): PendingIntent {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, actionType,
            Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.NOTION_ID_EXTRA, id)
                putExtra(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_TYPE, actionType)
            }, 0)
}
```

I found that the passed id was incorrect, after some searching I found out that I should include this flag in the broadcast: `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` so it's like this:

```
fun notificationAction(context: Context, id: String, actionType: Int): PendingIntent {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, actionType,
            Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.NOTION_ID_EXTRA, id)
                putExtra(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_TYPE, actionType)
            }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

Now the passed id is the right one, I still don't understand why did this happen, or why was the id extra completely different(yet not random, I kept seeing the same wrong id every time) without this flag.